# Не могу определить сигнал в классе, наследуемом от QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

в классе `GLOptions` определяю сигнал:

```
signals:
   void submit();
```

получаю ошибку компиляции:

> moc_gloptions.cpp:-1: ошибка: multiple definition of `GLOptions::submit()'

1. Файл `gloptions.h`:

   ```
   #ifndef GLOPTIONS_H
   #define GLOPTIONS_H

   #include <QWidget>
   #include "glprimitive.h"

   class GLOptions : public QWidget
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       explicit GLOptions(QWidget *parent = 0);
       ~GLOptions();

       GLPrimitive* getPrimitive();

       signals:
           void submit();
   };

   #endif // GLOPTIONS_H
   ```
2. Файл `gloptions.cpp`:

   ```
   #include "gloptions.h"

   GLOptions::GLOptions(QWidget *parent)
       : QWidget(parent)
   {
   }

   GLOptions::~GLOptions()
   {
   }

   void GLOptions::submit()
   {
   }

   GLPrimitive* GLOptions::getPrimitive()
   {
       return NULL;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

multiple definition - говорит, о том, что вы уже где-то ранее определили этот сигнал в заголовочном файле, возможно, как обычный public/private метод.